# How to use jade template engine in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, npm, pug

I want to use jade template engine in my angular app. I have install jade in my angular folder using `npm install jade`

Then I have included it in my index.jade like below

```
doctype html
 html
  head 
   title AngularApp
  body(ng-app="AngularApp", ng-init="message='hello world")
   h1 {{message}}
   script(src="node_modules/angular/angular.js")
   script(src="node_modules/jade/jade.js")
   script(src="scripts/app.js")
```

But I don't get the `hello world` output in my browser. so how to use jade template engine in angularjs.

I get the following output in my browser

```
Index of /

(drwxrwxr-x)        css/
(drwxrwxr-x)        node_modules/
(drwxrwxr-x)        scripts/
(-rw-rw-r--)    257B    index.jade

Node.js v4.4.7/ ecstatic server running @ localhost:8080
```

Also i am not getting any error in console.

Comment: Jade is a server side engine, it doesn't have anything to do with angular specifically.  What *do* you get in the browser?  And do you have any errors in your console?

Comment: well that has absolutely *nothing* to do with angular;  you don't have jade installed correctly in node.